# What is the proper translation for と続いた後で?

Tags: grammar, meaning

> ｘやｙなどと続いた後で、ｚという答えがあった。

Literally it means something like:

> The answers were x, y followed by z.

What is the better translation for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as the nuance goes, it is like saying:

> "After a (long) run/series of answers such as X and Y, there came Answer Z."

「～～と[続]{つづ}いた」 implies that it took a pretty long time for all the answers to be presented.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit why  the author used と before 続いた ?

Comment: @YasashiiEirian The と is quotative... I think.

Answer (score 1):

The answers x and y were followed by the answer z.

It can be used like this as well.

> ジョギングやジムの続いた後で、スイミングをしました
>
> After going for a a jog and to the gym, I went swimming.

In the above case, it implies that even though I did all of those exercises I still went swimming.